# Total differential intuition for minimizing

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am confused about total differentials and what do they signify? Can they act as normal variables. I was trying to solve a question:

Find the point(s) on each of the following surfaces which is closest to the origin. (Hint: the algebra is easier if you minimize the square of the distance, rather than the distance itself.):
$x^2 - yz -1 = 0$

When I am taking the total differential of the distance squared, I get $2x dx + 2y dy + 2z dz$. On taking the total differential of the constraint I get $2x dx - ydz -zdy = 0$. On substituting for $dz$ from the constraint into the total differential of the distance squared and then equating the partials of x and y to zero, I am getting points $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$ and $(0, \mp 1, \pm1)$. I am not sure what $(0, \mp 1, \pm1)$ signifies.

My understanding of the process is that the level surface of distance squared and constraint are tangent at the point where the distance is minimum. The total differential for the constraint tells us how does the dependent variable (z in my case) in the constraint varies with the  independent variables. At the tangent, by substituting for $dz$ , I am enforcing the fact that the small changes in z in relation to small  changes in x and y should be same on the both the constraint and the level surface. Making the partials zero for x and y then gives me the critical points.

What am I doing wrong here? What does the point $(0, \mp 1, \pm1)$ signify? (My feeling is that dz on the two surfaces cant be equated since the two gradients can have different lengths.)